# Assigning iam roles to multiple google cloud projects for a service account

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am going to give an iam role to a service account for 20 projects. I ran below command in the cloud shell and it works for one project. I am wondering how I can run one command for 20 projects.
Can I use a list for the project name?

```
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding my-project-name  --role roles/bigquery.dataEditor     --member serviceAccount:my-service-account
```

Comment: What Os are you running the command on?

Comment: If you have all the projects under the folder, you can grant the service account on the folder directly. Else, you have to perform a loop

Answer (score 0):

as @guillaume's suggestion, Applying folder level access control is applicable for this (or Org level if applicable) I believe these documentation are helpful references for this.

- Resource Hierarchy background: https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/resource-hierarchy-access-control#background
- Manage Access Controls: https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-changing-revoking-access
- Access control for folders: https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/access-control-folders#overview_of_iam_roles_for